# Concurrent use of a persistent PHP socket

Tags: php, apache, sockets, networking

I am wanting to use PHP to create a persistent socket connection to a notification service server and I am wondering how many Apache/PHP threads would be able to concurrently use the socket before I have problems. I have done some testing with this but I cannot seem to produce any problems.

---

**Edit**

I am using the socket like this:

```
$fh = pfsockopen('127.0.0.1', '1338');
fwrite($fh,$data);
```

Every PHP thread would share the same persistent socket

Comment: Could you provide a code example to help me imagine what you do?

Comment: You can create as many as your bandwidth/memory would allow, I assume...

Comment: How are you sharing the socket between threads? pthreads?

Comment: I added more details about how I am using it.

Comment: That's the first time I see this function. Could you link the documentation for this?

Comment: @MichelFeldheim http://us3.php.net/pfsockopen

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The limitation with `fsockopen` is the maximum amount of open file descriptors defined in the systems kernel settings. If `pfsockopen` is implemented well, it should only use one single socket connection, means only one file descriptor **per php process**.

You'll have to test this.

e.g.

```
$fd = pfsockopen('173.194.44.24', 80);
echo $fd;
```

This will output the id of the file descriptor: `Resource id #1`

Open this in a web browser and reload the page several times - you should see the same id each time you are using the same socket connection.

In a default **Apache prefork MPM - mod_php** setup you probably are randomly sent to different forked processes which will most likely result in n different ids cycling through, while n depends on your Apache configuration of

- `MinSpareServers` (<= n pConnections)
- `MaxSpareServers`  (>= n pConnections)
- `MaxRequestsPerChild` (tMax)

When you reach `MaxRequestsPerChild` the process is terminated and the persistent connection on this child as well.

In a Apache Worker MPM or any other fastcgi-capable webserver like Lighttpd or Nginx combined with PHP-FPM or PHP-cgi + fastcgi I am expecting the same behavior, now not caused by the webserver but by the php processes.

In parallel to the apache settings described above, the relevant settings are

**PHP-FPM**

- `pm.min_spare_servers` (<= n pConnections)
- `pm.max_spare_servers` (>= n pConnections)
- `pm.max_requests` (tMax)

**FastCGI**

- `PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN` (= n pConnections)
- `PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS` (tMax)

In all configurations the maximum lifetime of a persistent connection is (in amount of requests handled by that process) `tMax`, the max amount of parallel persistent connections `n pConnections`

Simulating this on the command-line (php-cli)

```
# php -a
Interactive shell                            # in a webserver environment this is the equivalent of one child

php > $fd1 = fsockopen( 'google.de', 80 );   # open non-persistent connection
php > echo $fd1 . "\n";
Resource id #1
php > $fd2 = fsockopen( 'google.de', 80 );   # open another one
php > echo $fd2 . "\n";
Resource id #2                               # new fd, new connection

php > $pd1 = pfsockopen( 'google.de', 80 );  # persistent connection
php > echo $pd1 . "\n";
Resource id #3                               # first persistent fd
php > $pd2 = pfsockopen( 'google.de', 80 );
php > echo $pd2 . "\n";                        
Resource id #3                               # uses the same connection

php > exit                                   # simulating MaxRequestsPerChild threshold
# php -a
Interactive shell

php > $pd3 = pfsockopen( 'google.de', 80 );  # persistent connection, same host
php > echo $pd3 . "\n";
Resource id #1                               # resource id reused because all old connections are gone
```

**EDIT**

Acually I forgot to mention a second limitation.
Connections of course can be closed anytime by the server itself.
This heavily depends on the server settings and protocol you are using.

Most servers close a connection after `n` seconds of silence and after `x` seconds of total connection time.

`pfsockopen` handles this silently, it simply opens a new connection when the old one is gone.

Simulating this on cli again:

```
# php -a
Interactive shell

php > $pd1 = pfsockopen( '127.0.0.1', 80 );
php > echo $pd1 . "\n";
Resource id #1
php > $pd1 = pfsockopen( '127.0.0.1', 80 );
php > echo $pd1 . "\n";
Resource id #1

(restarting my webserver on the another console /etc/init.d/nginx restart)

php > $pd1 = pfsockopen( '127.0.0.1', 80 );
php > echo $pd1 . "\n";
Resource id #2
```

Comment: Wow, this was a very thorough and well-formatted explanation. I was hoping that the answer would be basically that but I was unsure of my testing results. Thank you!