# pfsockopen doesn't seem to be working?

Tags: php, persistence

**My Environment**

I'm trying to run this PHP script in Windows 7 via the CLI.

**Test Background**

In order to establish an SSH one has to send and receive banner messages. You send "SSH-2.0-whatever\r\n" to the server, the server sends you back "SSH-2.0-whatever\r\n" back (this can be done the other way too) and then you get a message containing the algorithms that the server supports. ie.

(script 1)

```
<?php
$fsock = fsockopen('shell.sourceforge.net', 22);
echo fgets($fsock, 1024);
fputs($fsock, "SSH-2.0-test\r\n");
echo fread($fsock, 1024);
```

Here's the output:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
  ♥♀
¶ólÆÆ§w↔F;ï÷╝ähºv   ~diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-e
xchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1   ☼ssh-rsa,s
sh-dss   ¥aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des
-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator
.liu.se   ¥aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3de
s-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysato
r.liu.se   ihmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160
@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96   ihmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,
hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96   §none,zlib@
openssh.com   §none,zlib@openssh.com
```

**The code**

So given the output of the above it seems like these two scripts, run one after the other, should give the same output:

(script 2)

```
<?php
$fsock = pfsockopen('shell.sourceforge.net', 22);
echo fgets($fsock, 1024);
```

(script 3)

```
<?php
$fsock = pfsockopen('shell.sourceforge.net', 22);
fputs($fsock, "SSH-2.0-test\r\n");
echo fread($fsock, 1024);
```

Unfortunately, script 1 does not match script 2 and script 3 combined. script 3 seems to be running as though script 2 never did. The output:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3

SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
```

Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pfsockopen()` function is persistent per `PHP process`.

Every execution of a script through the **CLI SAPI** (as in your example) starts a new PHP process.

When script 2 ends, the PHP process also ends and the **persistent socket is closed**.

When script 3 starts, a new PHP process is created and a new persistent socket is initialized.

So script 3 starts an entirely new "conversation" with the remote server and that's why you get those results.

For a very good description of how persistent php sockets work: see: [Concurrent use of a persistent PHP socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268018/concurrent-use-of-a-persistent-php-socket)